# Cocoa Objective-C init oddity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, constructor, initializer

I was reviewing some code and came across something that looked like this (assume it is defined for the `TestObject` class)

```
-(id) init
{
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        self.testString = @"Hello";
    }
    return self;
}
```

I promptly changed

```
if (self == [super init])
```

to

```
if (self = [super init])
```

But then realised that (although I know it wasn't right) the code was working as it was, I isolated the original code, in an ultra simple program

```
    TestObject* testObject = [[TestObject alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", testObject.testString);
```

To my astonishment, this works. Why does the equality check instead of the assignment not break things? Why is

```
self == [super init]
```

true at the start of init, before I've even assigned it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`self` is already assigned for you. The purpose of assigning it to `[super init]` is to allow the superclass's `-init` implementation to return a different object. I highly recommend [The How and Why of Cocoa Initializers](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html) (Mike Ash) and [self = [stupid init];](http://blog.wilshipley.com/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html) (Wil Shipley) for more detailed discussion about why this is (or isn't) a good idea. You will find varying opinions on whether checking equality (`==`) is necessary.

As an aside, if you try to assign to `self` in any other method, you see this error message:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the links, very informative. I'm surprised Apple don't go into more detail about this in their introductory documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `self` pointer is established by `alloc`. The idiom

```
if(self = [super init])
{
...
}
```

is to protect against cases where the superclass' init needs to change the value. For example, some `init`s may signal failure by returning `nil`.